# Binding a TextBox to a ListBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding

I am currently trying to implement a relatively simple data management app.

I have a class `Member` and a `BindingList<Member> membersList`, as well as a `ListBox`and some `TextBox`es.

The `ListBox` is bound to `membersList`.

Now I, ideally, want to bind the `TextBox`es to `ListBox.SelectedItem`, so that whatever element the user has selected in the `ListBox`, when they edit a `TextBox` the element in `membersList`is updated.

I tried just binding the `TextBox`es to `ListBox.SelectedItem`, but this made the `Binding` to the actual element that `ListBox.SelectedItem` is referencing at the moment of the binding creation, not whichever item is selected in the `ListBox`.

```
firstNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text",
membersList.SelectedItem, "firstName", false,
DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

I actually solved this already by just clearing and recreating the `Bindings` for the `TextBox`es in the `membersList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` event handler, but this feels very "hacky" and I suspect there is a more standard solution.

Another idea I had was to just make the `Binding`s to a `Member temporaryMember` that is set to `ListBox.SelectedItem` inside the `membersList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` event handler, but then I have to manually write the changes through to the corresponding item in `membersList` which also makes me feel like this isn't the optimal solution.

Is there a way to make the `Binding` dynamic, in the sense that, upon creation, I indicate to it that the DataSource is changing?

Or a standard way the change the `Binding`s DataSource without deleting it and creating a new one? (Or is this actually best practice?)

(Another thing to mention: I am new to `Bindings` in C# and while searching for solutions, I found out that there apparently are two different classes, one in the `System.Windows.Data` namespace and another in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. I think I am using the class from the latter. Maybe I should use the other one?)

Comment: *I tried just binding the TextBoxes to ListBox.SelectedItem, but this made the Binding to the actual element that ListBox.SelectedItem is referencing at the moment of the binding creation, not whichever item is selected in the ListBox.* What does that mean? The item which is selected in `ListBox`, is `SelectedItem`.

Comment: `ListBox` have built-in support for two-way databindings. Use a `BindungList<T>` as data source which T implements `InotifyPropertyChanged`. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625054/3110834) for more information.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes, but the DataSource of the Binding is not changed, when `ListBox.SelectedItem` changes.

Comment: Can you verify the Binding? membersList.SelectedItem, "firstName" seems to bind to property firstName within source membersList.SelectedItem, and it looks wrong...

Comment: @Fab What do you mean? Yes, the TextBox is supposed to be bound to a property of the `ListBox.SelectedItem`?

Comment: As Reza Aghaei said and also setting the `BindingList` as the DataSource of a `BindingSource`. The TextBoxes just need a `Binding` set to the `BindingSource`, When an item is selected if the ListBox, the TextBoxes will update automatically. Also, when a member of the `BindingList` is changed/modified. The ListBox instead won't update the current ListItem if an Item of the `BindingList` is changed, but you just need to call `[BindingSource].ResetCurrentItem();` if this happens.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, I didn't know about the possibility to use an extra `BindingSource`. This seems to have done the trick! (If you want to write an answer, I'll mark it as correct)

Comment: Having a `BindingList<T>` you really don't need `BindingSource`, unless for design-time support and for using in `BindingNavigator`. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53294445/3110834) to see how you can setup a list box or a combo box as index in the form and bind other controls to selected item of the listbox/combo box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the comments, associating a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.-ctor) (or a DataTable) with a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.-ctor) can have some interesting benefits.

All bound controls are updated automatically when one of the elements of the `BindingList` is modified or a new element is added to the list.

You can use the `MovePrevious()`, `MoveNext()`, `MoveFirst()`, `MoveLast()` methods to navigate the elements in the `BindingList` (other useful methods and events are available, see the Docs about the BindingSource functionality).

Here, a `BindingList<T>` (where `T` is the `Member` class shown below) is set as the DataSource of a BindingSource. Both are Fields of a Form class, this can be modified as needed.
The BindingSource is then used as the DataSource of a ListBox.

The `Text` property of two TextBox controls is then bound, using the BindingSource, to one of the properties of the `Member` class. This way, the Text property is set to the current Item of the BindingList. All controls are *synchronized*:

```
txtMemberName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", membersSource, 
    "FirstName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
txtMemberLastName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", membersSource, 
    "LastName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

This is how it works, in practice:

[image: BindingSource and BindingList]

*Note that the current Item of the ListBox is updated in real time when the Text of a TextBox is modified.*

```
BindingList<Member> members = null;
BindingSource membersSource = null;

public partial class frmMembers : Form
{
    public frmMembers() {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeDataBinding();
    }

    private void InitializeDataBinding()
    {
        members = new BindingList<Member>();
        membersSource = new BindingSource(members, null);

        lstBoxMembers.DataSource = membersSource;
        txtMemberName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", membersSource, 
            "FirstName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        txtMemberLastName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", membersSource, 
            "LastName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }

    private void btnAddMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frmNew = new frmNewMember();
        if (frmNew.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && frmNew.newMember != null) {
            members.Add(frmNew.newMember);
        }
    }

    private void btnMovePrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (membersSource.Position > 0) {
            membersSource.MovePrevious();
        }
        else {
            membersSource.MoveLast();
        }
    }

    private void btnMoveNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (membersSource.Position == membersSource.List.Count - 1) {
            membersSource.MoveFirst();
        }
        else {
            membersSource.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Sample New Member Form:

```
public partial class frmNewMember : Form
{
    public Member newMember;

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMemberName.Text) || 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMemberLastName.Text)) return;
        newMember = new Member(txtMemberName.Text, txtMemberLastName.Text);
    }
}
```

---

Sample Member class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Member
{
    public Member() { }
    public Member(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
}
```